# Is there a way for a Champion to gain access to Cleric spells?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, champion

I'm building a Champion of Shelyn, and there are Cleric spells that I believe would be useful.

Is there a way for a Champion to gain access to Cleric spellcasting?

Comment: Clarification: are you looking for an answer about Cleric (Divine) Spells generally, or about *Magic Weapon* specifically? Notably, *Magic Weapon* appears on 3 of the 4 spell lists, so getting that spell specifically is much more broad than getting Divine spells.

Comment: When the question was originally asked, I was just looking to gain access to Magic Weapon, but after a short discussion with my DM, it made more sense for the character to take the dedication feats suggested to blend Cleric into the character.

Comment: Could you kindly edit your question so that the title and the body ask the same question in that case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am currently playing a champion who is a divine spellcaster. Here are some of the options I've explored:

### Dedications

The most straight-forward way is through dedications. You can gain access to divine spellcasting either by using the *Basic Cleric Spellcasting* dedication feat (Core Rulebook, pg.224).  This feat will give you access to a limited number of cleric spell slots based on your level. This can be done as early as level 4.

One downside to this approach is that clerics cast with wisdom, which doesn't synergize well with the champion's abilities. Try using the *Basic Sorcerer Spellcasting* dedication feat instead. You will cast using Charisma, which fits a bit better. You can get access to the divine spell list by choosing a relevant bloodline, such as celestial.

### Ancestry Feats

If you already had a different kind of spellcasting, you could use the he 5th level human ancestry feat *Adaptive Adept* gives you access to a divine 1st level spell. However, it requires access to 3rd level spells and a spellcasting class feature, making it undesirable for your use case.

Some ancestries have other feats that grant access to cantrips or 1st level spells. For example, the Gnome *First World Magic* ancestry feat grants you a cantrip. Wellspring Gnomes can choose a divine cantrip, rather than a primal one.

### Scrolls

Outside of class features, you can also use scrolls.